# Ngx-Spinner is not working in feature module

Tags: angular, spinner

`Ngx-Spinner` it is working fine when i call it in inside the main module i.e. `app-module`.

I am using `line spinner` on complete page so i define it inside the `app-component.html`

`<ngx-spinner bdColor="rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.47)" size="medium" color="#fff" type="line-spin-clockwise-fade"></ngx-spinner>`

but in case of when i am trying to show this spinner by calling from a component of feature module , it is not working .

Comment: Share the code what you had tried with so far.

Comment: I think we need to see your imports declaration.

Comment: It still needs to be in the html file for the component where you activate 'show()' or 'hide()'. Is this the case?

Comment: @rrd it is not mandatory that it should be present in the same component from where we put the call of `show` and `hide` , its working fine in case of mine in which i am putting `<ng-spinner>` tag in the  `app-root.component.html` and displaying it from its child component.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move this ngx-spinner into separate component. You can call this spinner component using Subject/BehaviorSubject using next() operator in the source component.

You can listen for the data in the 'ngx-spinner' component using subscribe method for display/hide the spinner.

Answer (score 1):

When working with feature modules and lazy loading, you also need to import the `NgxSpinnerModule` into your feature module.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        NgxSpinnerModule,
        ...
    ],
})
export class FeatureModule { ... }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

> Separating out your commonly used modules with a shared module file is a good practice.
>   So, your `SharedModule` would be -

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        NgxSpinnerModule,
    ],
    exports: [    // optional in your case
        NgxSpinnerModule
    ],
    providers: [
        // ...
    ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Then,

- Just import this wherever your `NgxSpinnerModule` is required.
- You may add many external modules to the same as required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [example in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-spinner-example)

In your module import NgxSpinnerModule

```
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from "ngx-spinner";


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule, NgxSpinnerModule
  ]
})
export class UserModule { }
```